# After adding a click event that shows a star, it does not register where it clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

With just the `#seven.click` method, the console prints touch just fine.  However after I add the mouse down even, it does not register.  Sometimes it registers if I click sporadically in the seven div, but it is unreliable.

So both the `$document.mousedown` and `#seven.click` work perfectly independently, but together only the mousedown fires.

How do I get them both to work at the same time?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
      $('.stars').show();
      $('.stars').css({'top': e.clientY - 15, 'left': e.clientX-15})
      .on('mouseup', function(e) {
        $('.stars').hide();
      });
    });
    $("#seven").click( function() {
        console.log("touch");
    });
});
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="containers">
  <img src="calc.jpg" />
  <img src="star.png" class="stars" id="myimg"/>
    <div id="screen"><span id="spScreen">0</span></div>
    <div id="seven" class="abs backGreen"></div>
    <div id="eight" class="abs backGreen"></div>
    <div id="nine" class="abs backGreen"></div>
    <div id="four" class="abs backGreen"></div>
    <div id="five" class="abs backGreen"></div>
    <div id="six" class="abs backGreen"></div>
    <div id="multiply" class="abs backGreen"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically I want an image to appear where i click and then disappear, but also at the same time run a function depending on where I click.

Comment: What you want to do here?

Comment: Add your HTML code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following snippet to see if it suits your needs:

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    .star {
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    .box {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      color: #fff;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    .box.red {
      background: #f00;
    }
    .box.green {
      background: #0f0;
    }
    .box.blue {
      background: #00f;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="box red" data-callback="redFunction"></div>
  <div class="box green" data-callback="greenFunction"></div>
  <div class="box blue" data-callback="blueFunction"></div>
  <div class="box red" data-callback="redFunction"></div>
  <div class="box green" data-callback="greenFunction"></div>
  <div class="box blue" data-callback="blueFunction"></div>
  <div class="box red" data-callback="redFunction"></div>
  <div class="box green" data-callback="greenFunction"></div>
  <div class="box blue" data-callback="blueFunction"></div>
  <div class="box red" data-callback="redFunction"></div>
  <div class="box green" data-callback="greenFunction"></div>
  <div class="box blue" data-callback="blueFunction"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function redFunction() {
      var boxes = $('.box.red').html('red!');
      setTimeout(function() {
        boxes.empty();
      }, 2000);
    }

    function greenFunction() {
      var boxes = $('.box.green').html('green!');
      setTimeout(function() {
        boxes.empty();
      }, 2000);
    }

    function blueFunction() {
      var boxes = $('.box.blue').html('blue!');
      setTimeout(function() {
        boxes.empty();
      }, 2000);
    }

    function onDocumentMouseDown(e) {

      var css = {
        top: e.pageY - 15,
        left: e.pageX - 15
      };

      $('<i class="fa fa-star star" />')
        .css(css)
        .appendTo('body');

      var $target = $(e.target);

      if ($target.data('callback')) {
        var callback = window[$target.data('callback')];
        if (typeof callback == 'function') {
          callback.apply(this);
        }
      }

    }

    function onDocumentMouseUp() {

      $('.star').remove();

    }

    $(document).on('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown).on('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is part of what I'm looking for.  I also want it to run a function depending on where I click.  Like have 3 boxes, a red one and a green one and a text box.  If I click the red box, the star flashes, but also the text box says red.  If I click the green box, the star flashes, but also the text box now says green.  Does that make sense?

Comment: what red boxes? can you provide a HTML sample?

Comment: not specifically red boxes... it was just an example... my code should flash a star and then show "touch" in the console... in the future I want it to do other things (other than log touch), depending on where I click..  but it will always flash the star

Comment: Had to go through the code a couple times to understand, still amateur.  This works perfect though, exactly what I needed.  Thanks!!.. Sorry my questions were worded so weird.

Answer (score 0):

This actually works fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/j6oz84rx/

I'm using your code, except I used `console.log` in place of the `.show` calls you were using. Make sure you don't have some error in your console that's happening after mouseDown?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
      console.log("working");
    });
    $("#seven").click( function() {
        console.log("touch");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure about what behavior you are expecting, but here is a guess :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#some-container-more-specific-that-document')
      .on('mousedown', function(e) {
          $('.stars').show();
          $('.stars').css({'top': e.clientY - 15, 'left': e.clientX-15});
      })
      .on('mouseup', function(e) {
          $('.stars').hide();
      });

    $("#seven").click( function() {
        console.log("touch");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function() 
{
    $(document).on('mousedown', function(e) 
    {
      $('.stars').show();
      $('.stars').css({'top': e.clientY - 15, 'left': e.clientX-15});
    }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
        $('.stars').hide();
      });
    $("#seven").on("mousedown", function() {
        console.log("touch");
    });
});
```